# Default SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout setting in serverwide

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-config, timeout, connection-timeout

For some reasons, I need to set higher duration for default ConnectionTimeout for asp.net to sql connection. Because some sites, during installing database, which has not connection string yet in web.config, need to execute long sql commands to create sql databases. And I need to allow those installs higher ConnectionTimeout value. Where do I do that? note that there is no connection string key in web.config if database is not created. Thats why I need to change default value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no connection string which you have created then you can change the timeout like this:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;   //By default the value is 30
```

Apply this to the place where you are going to execute your query from the code.

If you want to make the above code a bit generic then you can create the below change in the `appsettings.config`

```
<appSettings>    
   <add key="SqlCommandTimeOut" value="90"/>
</appSettings>
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlCommandTimeOut"]);
```

Comment: If I add    <add key="SqlCommandTimeOut" value="90"/> to appsettings.config file, will it take affect for newly created site which has no SqlCommandTimeOut value in their web.config file? Btw where is appsettings.config file ?

Comment: Also I do not have access to source codes. I am only hosting sites.